# Excel VBA. ExportasFixedFormat not including images and print areas are off

Tags: excel, export-to-pdf, vba

From my main workbook, I am opening a second workbook and trying to export that file to a pdf.
I am having troubles with defining the print areas, and it will not export the graphics.

Here is my code.

```
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFileDirectory & sFileName
                    ' Now put in the signature
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("Signature").Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("SignatureModel")
                    'Now prepare the PDF setup

                    'ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
                    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
                    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
                    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
                    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
                    'Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea).Select

                    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sFileDirectory & PDFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=False

                    ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

I have tried setting the print area with pagesetup commands and/or setting the print area in the second file before opening it.  Not clear on how this is supposed to work. Also, it will not export the image of my signature.
Any help would be great.
Thanks,